# Error in using GDAL Java binding

Tags: gdal, java, coordinate-system

I am using the Java binding of GDAL to project a set of coordinate points from UTM to lat/log using the CoordinateTransformation Class of GDAL. I have written the code as follows:

```
SpatialReference oUTM = new SpatialReference();
SpatialReference oLatLog = new SpatialReference();

oUTM.SetProjCS("UTM 44/ WGS84");
oUTM.SetWellKnownGeogCS("WGS84");
oUTM.SetUTM(44, 1);

oLatLog = oUTM.CloneGeogCS();

double[] arr = new double[2];
arr[0]=10;
arr[1]=10;

double x = arr[0] , y = arr[1];

CoordinateTransformation transform = new CoordinateTransformation(oUTM,oLatLog);

transform.TransformPoint(arr);

System.out.println("Before:"+x+" "+y+"\nAfter:"+arr[0]+" "+arr[1]);
```

But when I run this in my main function, I get the following error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:

`org.gdal.osr.osrJNI.new_SpatialReference__SWIG_1()J
    at org.gdal.osr.osrJNI.new_SpatialReference__SWIG_1(Native Method)
    at org.gdal.osr.SpatialReference.<init>(SpatialReference.java:117)
    at controller.CrsConverterGDAL.main(CrsConverterGDAL.java:8)`

Does anyone know how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 3):

To overcome unsatisfiedlinkerror in gdal you need to check that your program is able to read the correct gdal environment variables and .dll files. Here is a brief procedure.

Now Follow the below mentioned Setup procedure.

Download and extract the gdal zip file from its site and save in some drive preferably C drive.

Now enter the follwing data in your PC Environmental Variables.

1. SET variable name = **GDAL_DATA** and variable value = **C:\gdal\bin\gdal-data**
2. SET variable name = **GDAL_DRIVER_PATH** and variable value = **C:\gdal\bin\gdal\plugins**
3. APPEND in variable name = **PATH** and variable value = **C:\gdal\bin**
4. APPEND in variable name = **PATH** and variable value = **C:\gdal\bin\gdal\apps**
5. Then you need to paste four .dll files i.e, **gdalconstjni.dll, gdaljni.dll, ogrjni.dll and osrjni.dll** from C:\gdal\bin\gdal\java to your jdk bin folder.

The 4 step is required if you want to use the gdal tools from any location in your PC.

The step 5 is specifically for java.

You need to include **gdal.jar in your project classpath** which you have already done.

Just ensure **x86 and x64 type of java and gdal used in your program**.

For more information refer to [java blogs](http://geospatialearth.in/blogs.php)

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration gdal/java binding doesn't work. If you are using Linux use the steps in https://github.com/VertNet/reproject/wiki/GDAL-Java-Bindings

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem and eventually realized that the gdal version I had in my build.gradle file (v3.0.0) was newer than and apparently incompatible with the gdal version installed on my computer (v2.4.2). I changed the version number in build.gradle to 2.4.2 and it worked.